# How to find the optimum word length of a group element?

Tags: group-theory

I have a (large, finite, permutation) group, and a group element that I know is a product of length=20 of the generators. But when I ConvertGroupElementToWord, I get a word of length=118. Other, unfamiliar elements have comparably long word lengths. 
How do I get an optimum (shortest) word length for any element?

Comment: I assume that by `ConvertGroupElementToWord` you mean simply the [`GroupElementToWord`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GroupElementToWord.html) function. Nevertheless, could you clarify your question with a few more details for the non-initiated?

Comment: Group theory is not Mathematica's strong suit. In the Options section of the docs, there are some parameters you could try to tweak, but there's not a built-in way to find the shortest word. I know it is in principle possible (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_problem_for_groups) , but I'm not aware of an efficient algorithm.

Comment: See also https://mathoverflow.net/questions/252535/expressing-permutations-in-terms-of-generators